# Как построить распределенную БД MySQL с автономной работой узлов?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, кластер

Дано: 3 сервера MySQL в 3 разных городах. Нужно настроить синхронизацию данных между ними (мультимастер). Но при этом, при отключении узла от сети он должен продолжать работать для локальных клиентов на чтение и запись, а после появления связи синхронизироваться с остальными. Каким может быть решение в подобном случае и есть ли оно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение для асинхронной репликации - https://www.symmetricds.org/
Symmetric DS позволяет настроить репликацию таким образом, чтобы при потере связи узлы работали автономно, а при появлении - синхронизировались. Возможные конфликты ключей нужно разруливать самостоятельно (например, offset'ами)